# Metric $ d(f,g):=\inf_{\gamma >0}{\{\mu(|f-g|>\gamma)+\gamma\}} $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(A,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $X$ be Banach space.

Take $\mathcal{L}^0$ be space of all $\mu$- mesurable fubction $f:E\to X$.

Let $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^0$, we define 
$$
d(f,g):=\inf_{\gamma >0}{\{\mu(|f-g|>\gamma)+\gamma\}}
$$
I want to show that $d$ is metric. But I don't understand why:
$$
d(f,g)=0\Rightarrow f=g
$$

An idea please

Comment: Note that $f=g$ in such a situation means that $f(t)=g(t)$ holds almost everywhere (for $t\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: How to say that $d(f,g)=0\Rightarrow f=g$ $a.e$

Comment: If the infimum over $\gamma>0$ is zero, there must exist a sequence $\gamma_n > 0$  so that $\mu(|f-g|> \gamma_n) + \gamma_n \to 0$ $n\to \infty$. Since the measure is positive, $\gamma_n \to 0$. Conclude using the continuity of the measure $\mu$ that $\mu(|f-g|>0)=0$.